# Unable to retrieve email through Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, codeigniter

I am using the Facebook API for login in the CodeIgniter framework; I am able to retrieve the username and id but am unable to get the email. I have read about the permissions, yet no lead in this regard.

My controller:

```
public function login()
{

        $this->load->library('facebook');

        $user = $this->facebook->getUser();


        if ($user) {
            try {
                $data['user_profile'] = $this->facebook->api('/me');
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                $user = null;
            }
        }else {
            // Solves first time login issue. (Issue: #10)
            $this->facebook->destroySession();
        }
        if ($user) {
            $data['logout_url'] = site_url('user_module/facebook_logout'); // Logs off application
            // OR 
            // Logs off FB!
            // $data['logout_url'] = $this->facebook->getLogoutUrl();
        } else {
            $data['login_url'] = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
           // 'redirect_uri' => site_url('user_module/home'),
            'scope' => array("email") // permissions here
            ));
        }

        $this->load->view('user_login',$data);
}
```

The view file:

```
<?php if (@$user_profile):  // call var_dump($user_profile) to view all data ?>
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
             <img class="img-thumbnail" data-src="holder.js/140x140" alt="140x140" src="https://graph.facebook.com/<?=$user_profile['id']?>/picture?type=large" style="width: 140px; height: 140px;">
             <h2><?=$user_profile['name']?></h2>
             <h2><?=$user_profile['id']?></h2>
             <h2><?=$user_profile['email']?></h2>
             <h2><?=$user_profile['user_location']?></h2>
             <a href="<?=$user_profile['link']?>" class="btn btn-lg btn-default btn-block" role="button">View Profile</a>
             <a href="<?= $logout_url ?>" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" role="button">Logout</a>
         </div>
     </div>
<?php else: ?>
      <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Login with Facebook</h2>
      <a href="<?= $login_url ?>" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" role="button">Login</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to make it easier to understand for the users who will answer you. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

"Declarative Fields" is what you need, see the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

For example: `$this->facebook->api('/me?fields=name,email')`

Comment: showing this error:- App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app admin for permissions.

Comment: well, the error message is completely unrelated to your question, and self explanatory. your app is not live, and you are not trying as a user with a role in the app.

Comment: i am using localhost,should i use my domain name instead?

Comment: that´s unrelated too...just put it live or use an app admin, and make sure the settings are ok

Comment: its working fine with admin id,but not working correctly for my test id

Comment: then put the app live in the app settings

Comment: By which he means *put it live **on Facebook***

Comment: @JonStory how to put it live on facebook? Any lead will be highly appreciated.

Comment: app settings > status & review > "Do you want to make this app and all its live features available to the general public?"